# C++ Identifying the Frequency of words occurring in a sentence

Tags: c++

What is the best STL to use for this task? I've been using `Map`, 
and I couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure how I am supposed to check the number of same words that occur in the sentence for example:

> I love him, I love her, he love her.

So I want the program to prompt the user to enter an integer, lets say i enter 3, the output will be love as the same word occurs 3 times in the sentence. But what method to use if I want to do a program like this?

Currently my program prompts for the user to enter the word, and then it shall return how many time that word occurs, which for word love, is 3. but now i want it the other way round. Can it be done? Using which STL will be better?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use a map to store the number of occurrences.
Well,you first have to understand this,since you are using a map,the key is unique while the stored data may not be unique.
Consider a map, x
with contents

```
x["I"]=3
x["Love"]=3
x["C"]=5
```

There is unique a mapping from the key to the value,and not the other way round,if you want this one to one mapping ,i would suggest a different data structure.If you want to use map,and still search for an element,using STL search function or your own.Or you can write your search function.
[search()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/).

```
map<string,int>::iterator ser;
cin>>check;
for(ser=x.begin();ser!=x.end();++ser)
{
    if(ser->second==check)
    {
       cout<<"Word"<<ser->first<<endl;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ser is the iterator of the map.

Answer (score 3):

First build the mapping from word to count and then build the reverse multi-mapping from that. Finally, you can determine which words occur with a given frequency:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::string str("I love him, I love her, he love her");
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;

    std::map<std::string, int> word_count;
    std::for_each(begin, end, [&](const std::string& s)
    {
        ++word_count[s];
    });

    std::multimap<int, std::string> count_words;
    std::for_each(word_count.begin(), word_count.end(),
                  [&](const std::pair<std::string, int>& p)
    {
        count_words.insert(std::make_pair(p.second, p.first));
    });

    auto its = count_words.equal_range(3);
    std::for_each(its.first, its.second,
                  [](const std::pair<int, std::string>& p)
    {
        std::cout << p.second << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, this does not correctly account for other punctuation in the input string, eg. `her,` and `her` have separate entries in `word_count`, along with 'him,'. You might need to postprocess word_count to strip out non-alpha characters and rebucket or discard. Hyphenated words and other embedded non-alpha are still problematic.

Answer (score 2):

```
/******************************************************************
Name  :  Paul Rodgers
Source : HW1.CPP
Compiler :  Visual C++ .NET
Action : Program will read in from standard input and determine the
         frequency of word lengths found in input.  An appropriate
         table is also displayed.  Maximum word length is 15 characters
         words greater then 15 are counted as length 15. 
         Average word length also displayed.

Note   : Words include hyphenated and ones with apostrophes.  Words with
         apostrophes, i.e. Jim's, will count the apostrophe as part of the
         word length. Hyphen is counted if word on same line, else not.

         Also an int array is used to hold the number of words with
         length associated with matching subscript, with subscript 0
         not being used.  So subscript 1 corresponds to word length of 1,
         subscript 2 to word length of 2 and so on.
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int NextWordLength(void);                    // function prototypes
void DisplayFrequencyTable(const int Words[]);

const int WORD_LENGTH = 16;                // global constant for array

void main()
{
  int WordLength;                         // actual length of word 0 to X
  int NumOfWords[WORD_LENGTH] = {0};     // array holds # of lengths of words

  WordLength = NextWordLength();
  while (WordLength)                   // continue to loop until no word, i.e. 0
    {                                 // increment length counter
      (WordLength <= 14) ? (++NumOfWords[WordLength]) : (++NumOfWords[15]);
      WordLength = NextWordLength();
    }

  DisplayFrequencyTable(NumOfWords);
}

/**********************  NextWordLength  ********************************
Action  : Will determine the length of the next word. Hyphenated words and
          words with apostrophes are counted as one word accordingly
Parameters : none
Returns   : the length of word, 0 if none, i.e. end of file
-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int NextWordLength(void)
{
  char Ch;
  int EndOfWord = 0,       //tells when we have read in one word
      LengthOfWord = 0;

  Ch = cin.get();                           // get first character
  while (!cin.eof() && !EndOfWord)
   {
     while (isspace(Ch) || ispunct(Ch))      // Skips leading white spaces
        Ch = cin.get();                      // and leading punctation marks

     if (isalnum(Ch))          // if character is a letter or number
        ++LengthOfWord;        // then increment word length

     Ch = cin.get();           // get next character

     if ((Ch == '-') && (cin.peek() == '\n')) //check for hyphenated word over two lines
       {
         Ch = cin.get();       // don't count hyphen and remove the newline char
         Ch = cin.get();       // get next character then on next line
       }

     if ((Ch == '-') && (isalpha(cin.peek()))) //check for hyphenated word in one line
     {
         ++LengthOfWord;       // count the hyphen as part of word
         Ch = cin.get();       // get next character
     }

     if ((Ch == '\'') && (isalpha(cin.peek()))) // check for apostrophe in word
      {
        ++LengthOfWord;        // count apostrophe in word length
        Ch = cin.get();        // and get next letter
      }

     if (isspace(Ch) || ispunct(Ch) || cin.eof())  // is it end of word
       EndOfWord++;
   }

  return LengthOfWord;
}

/***********************  DisplayFrequencyTable  **************************
Action      :  Will display the frequency of length of words along with the
               average word length
Parameters
  IN        : Pointer to array holding the frequency of the lengths
Returns     : Nothing
Precondition: for loop does not go beyond WORD_LENGTH
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void DisplayFrequencyTable(const int Words[])
{
  int TotalWords = 0, TotalLength = 0;

  cout << "\nWord Length      Frequency\n";
  cout << "------------     ----------\n";

  for (int i = 1; i <= WORD_LENGTH-1; i++)
    {
     cout << setw(4) << i << setw(18) << Words[i] << endl;
     TotalLength += (i*Words[i]);
     TotalWords += Words[i];
    }

  cout << "\nAverage word length is ";

  if (TotalLength)
     cout << float(TotalLength)/TotalWords << endl;
  else
    cout << 0 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the code snippet. But are you sure this helps? An explanation of what you do and exemplary code helps much more on the long view. Code might just be copied without understanding or even reading it. In this case the code doesn't even seem to solve the problem from the question above :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<cstddef>
#include<map>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::map;

int main() {

    cout << "Please enter a string: " << endl;
    string str;
    getline(cin, str, '\n');

    size_t str_len = str.size();
    cout << endl << endl;

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    bool pop = false;

    map<string, int> myMap;

    for (size_t k = 0; k < str_len-1; k++) {
        if (((k == 0) && isalpha(str[0])) || (!(isalpha(str[k-1])) && isalpha(str[k])))
            i = k;
        if ( isalpha(str[k]) && !(isalpha(str[k+1])) ) {
            j = k;
            pop = true;
        }
        if ( (k == str_len-2) && isalpha(str[k+1]) ) {
            j = k+1;
            pop = true;
        }

        if ( (i <= j) && pop ) {
            string tmp = str.substr(i, j-i+1);
            cout << tmp << '\t';
            myMap[tmp]++;
            pop = false;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    map<string, int>::iterator itr, end = myMap.end();
    for (itr = myMap.begin(); itr != end; itr++)
        cout << itr->first << "\t - - - - - \t" << itr->second << endl;

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answers which are just a block of code with no explanation are not useful. Please take the time to explain how this code answers OP's question.